# Use of sympy and scipy results in bad behaviour, where is my error?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, derivative, calculus

I am writing a code in which I calculate derivatives and integrals. For that I use `sympy` and `scipy.integrate`, respectively. But the use results in a strange erroneous, behaviour. Below is a minimal code that reproduces the behaviour:

```
from scipy.integrate import quadrature
import sympy
import math

def func(z):
    return math.e**(2*z**2)+3*z

z = symbols('z')
f = func(z)
dlogf_dz = sympy.Lambda(z, sympy.log(f).diff(z))
print(dlogf_dz)
print(dlogf_dz(10))

def integral(z):
    # WHY DO I HAVE TO USE [0] BELOW ?!?!
    d_ARF=dlogf_dz(z[0])
    return d_ARF

result = quadrature(integral, 0, 3)
print(result)

>>> Lambda(z, (4.0*2.71828182845905**(2*z**2)*z + 3)/(2.71828182845905**(2*z**2) + 3*z))
>>> 40.0000000000000
>>> (8.97457203290041, 0.00103422711649337)
```

The first 2 print statements deliver mathematically correct results, but the integration outcome `result` is wrong - instead of ~8.975 it should be exactly 18. I know this, because I double-checked with WolframAlpha, since `dlogf_dz` is mathematically quite simple, you can check for yourself [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%284.0*2.71828182845905**%282*z**2%29*z%20%2B%203%29%2F%282.71828182845905**%282*z**2%29%20%2B%203*z%29%20from%200%20to%203).

Strangely enough, if I just hard-code the math-expression from my first print statement into `integral(z)`, I get the right answer:

```
def integral(z):
    d_ARF=(4.0*2.71828182845905**(2*z**2)*z + 3)/(2.71828182845905**(2*z**2) + 3*z)
    return d_ARF

result = quadrature(integral, 0, 3)
print(result)

>>> (18.000000063540558, 1.9408245677254854e-07)
```

I think the problem is that I don't provide `dlogf_dz` to `integral(z)` in a correct way, I have to somehow else define `dlogf_dz` as a function. Note, that I defined `d_ARF=dlogf_dz(z[0])` in `integral(z)`, else the function was giving errors.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the code, more precisely make `dlogf_dz` compatible with `sympy` integrations?** Tnx

Comment: Documentation for `sympy.lambdify`, the preferred tool for creating `numpy` compatible functions from `sympy` exprssions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sympy environment where `z` is a symbol, I can create a `numpy` compatible function from a sympy expression using `lambdify` (not `Lambda`).

```
In [22]: expr = E**(2*z**2)+3*z

In [23]: fn = lambdify(z, log(expr).diff(z))

In [24]: quad(fn,0,3)

Out[24]:
```

[image]

`lambdify` produced this function:

```
In [25]: help(fn)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(z)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(z)
    
    Expression:
    
    (4*z*exp(2*z**2) + 3)/(3*z + exp(2*z**2))
```

`lambdify` isn't fool proof but is the best tool for using `sympy` and `scipy` together.

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html

Comment: Thank you, this did what I wanted! Can you tell me what you mean by "lambify isn't fool proof"? That it isn't always numerically accurate?

Comment: Did you read the documentation link I provided? For some expressions it doesn't work.  Or it will work with some array inputs but not others.  There have been a number SO about problems with `lambdify`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, never mix sympy with other numerical packages. For example, you wrote:

```
def func(z):
    return math.e**(2*z**2)+3*z
```

Let's replace `math.e` with `sympy.E`:

```
def func(z):
    return sympy.E**(2*z**2)+3*z
```

Now, before integrating with Scipy, since this appears to be a relatively easy expression I would try with SymPy:

```
dlogf_dz = sympy.log(f).diff(z)
dlogf_dz.integrate((z, 0, 3)).n()
# out: 18.0000001370698
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I upvoted your answer! Actually the function `func(z)` above is intentionally simply for the purpose of showing minimal working code. In my real code I will have a much more complicated function and I read that `sympy.integrate` frequently fails to integrate tougher functions, hence I should be using `scipy`. So can you tell me how to make the `scipy` integration work with a `sympy` expression?